# Is this powershell script a good way to find the owner then change the owner

Tags: file, loops, powershell, ownership

I wrote a Powershell v3 script to list all the files owned by a user on our file server.  It ran for 3 hours before I stopped it. It has to go through 619,238 Files and 57,452 Folders (517 GB). What order of magnitude should this take? Is there a way to improve the speed?

I tried to do this using pipes, but failed to get anything to work.

It's running on a Vmware virtual machine running Windows 2009 R2 SP1 with 4GB of memory. It uses about 60% of the CPU when I run it.

Here the code I wrote. I am very new to Powershell, but I have a lot of experience with Perl. My co-workers said to write a bat file.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1
.DESCRIPTION
   List all the files that a given user owns
.PARAMETER none
   username: user 
   logfile: path to log file. This is optional. If omitted the the log file is created "u:\scratch\<$username>-files.txt
.EXAMPLE
    C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo
    Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo u:\scratch\log.txt

#>

param (
    [string]$username,
    [string]$logfile
    )


# Load modules
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

function printHelp {
    Write-Host "This script will find all the files owned by a user. It scans \\dfs\groups"
    Write-Host "C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 user logfile (optional)"
    Write-Host "Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo"
    Write-Host "Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo u:\scratch\log.txt"
}

if ($logfile -eq "") {
    $logfile = "u:\scratch\" + $username + "-files.txt"
    Write-Host "Setting log file to $logfile"
}

# you must use a UNC path
[String]$path = "\\dfs\u$\groups"
[String]$AD_username = "AMS\" + $username

# check that we have a valid AD user
if (!(Get-QADUser $AD_username)){
    Write-Host "ERROR: Not a valid AD User: $AD_username"
    Exit 0
}

Write-Output "Listing all files owned by $username from $path" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile 
Write-Host "Listing all files owned by $username from $path"
$d = Get-Date
Write-Output $d | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append

$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $f = Get-Acl $file.FullName

    $d = [string]::Compare($file.FullName, $username, $True)
    if (($f.Owner -eq $username) -or ($f.Owner -eq $AD_username))
    {
        Write-Host "$file.FullName"
        Write-Output $file.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    }
}

Write-Host "Completed"
exit 0
```

The next step I have to do is modify the script above to find the files owned by a given user and change them to their manager.

This is the script I found to change the owner. It will be in a loop which walks the filesystem. Is this a good way to do this.

```
$username=”dnp”
$domain=”ams”
$ID = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($domain, $username)

# file to change owner. must be UNC path
$path = "\\dfs\c$\ams\psscripts\test.txt"
write-host $path
$acl = get-acl $path
$acl.SetOwner($ID)
set-acl -path $path -aclObject $acl
```

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what order of magnitude that should take but to improve the speed you could start by removing the redundant compare in your `foreach` loop:

```
$d = [string]::Compare($file.FullName, $username, $True)
```

String comparison is costly and you're not using `$d`.  You're also comparing against $username or "AMS\" + $username which again is costly.  I can't see why you need to compare against both.  I've modified your script to add timing to it.  I would recommend trying it on a subset of the files to get some empirical data to work out how long the full set would take.  Bear in mind that the total size of the files is irrelevant in this case as you aren't processing them, just their properties.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1
.DESCRIPTION
   List all the files that a given user owns
.PARAMETER none
   username: user 
   logfile: path to log file. This is optional. If omitted the the log file is created "u:\scratch\<$username>-files.txt
.EXAMPLE
    C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo
    Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo u:\scratch\log.txt

#>

param (
    [string]$username,
    [string]$logfile
    )


# Load modules
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
#Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

function printHelp {
    Write-Host "This script will find all the files owned by a user. It scans \\dfs\groups"
    Write-Host "C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 user logfile (optional)"
    Write-Host "Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo"
    Write-Host "Example: C:\ams\psscripts\list-files.ps1 plo u:\scratch\log.txt"
}

#StopWatch
$stopWatch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$stopWatch.Start()

if ($logfile -eq "") {
    $logfile = "e:\scratch\" + $username + "-files.txt"
    Write-Host "Setting log file to $logfile"
}

# you must use a UNC path
[String]$path = "\\test-server\testfolder\subfolder"
[String]$AD_username = "AMS\" + $username

# check that we have a valid AD user
if (!(Get-QADUser $AD_username)){
    Write-Host "ERROR: Not a valid AD User: $AD_username"
    Exit 0
}

Write-Output "Listing all files owned by $username from $path" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile 
Write-Host "Listing all files owned by $username from $path"
$d = Get-Date
Write-Output $d | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append

$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Output ("Setup time: {0}." -f $stopWatch.Elapsed) | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
$stopWatch.Reset()

$stopWatch.Start()
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse
$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Output ("Got {0} files to process, took {1}" -f $files.Count, $stopWatch.Elapsed) | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
$stopWatch.Reset()

$stopWatch.Start()
Foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $f = Get-Acl $file.FullName

    #$d = [string]::Compare($file.FullName, $username, $True)
    #if (($f.Owner -eq $username) -or ($f.Owner -eq $AD_username))
    if ($f.Owner -eq $AD_username)
    {
        Write-Host ("{0}" -f $file.FullName)
        Write-Output $file.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    }
}
$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Output ("Processed {0} files, took {1}" -f $files.Count, $stopWatch.Elapsed) | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append

Write-Host "Completed"
exit 0
```

Running this yielded the following results in our infrastructure:
Got 37803 files to process, took 00:00:57.5834897
Processed 37803 files, took 00:10:42.2988004

Your original code took 15 minutes to process the same number of files:
Processed 37803 files, took 00:15:04.1024350

Added @GeorgeR.Jenkins in memory string construction but it didn't make a significant reduction to the processing time:
Processed 37803 files, took 00:10:26.7815446

Interestingly attempting to pipe the get-childitem to a where clause didn't improve the performance.  Using

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | where {(Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner -eq $AD_username} <br/>
```

which will only return files with the correct owner so no processing was needed later yielded: 
Got 46 files to process, took 00:13:51.4940596

That all said, if you where running on similar infrastructure to me I would expect, at the fastest rate I've seen, which is 59 files per second, that your 619,238 files would take around 175 minutes.  The rate I got with your original code was 42 files per second, which would have taken 246 minutes.  Again I would advise running on your system with a small subset of the files to calculate how long it will take before running the whole set.

Comment: Thanks for the help it runs faster now. In the line Write-Output $file.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append is there a way to also write out $file.LastWriteTime without the path being truncated? I tried a few ways without success.

Comment: With two simple text files log.txt and file.txt I used this:
`$log = Get-Item log.txt
$file = Get-Item fileFound.txt
$textOutput = ("{0}, Last write time: {1}" -f $file.FullName, $file.LastWriteTime)
Write-Host $textOutput
Write-Output $textOutput | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append -Encoding ASCII`
Simply create the string you want to write first and then write it to your file.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I didn't completely understand what you did. So, I did this: `$textOutput = ("{0}, Last write time: {1}" -f $file.FullName, $file.LastWriteTime); 
Write-Host $textOutput;
Write-Output $textOutput | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append -Encoding ASCII;`

Comment: No problem, that's basically the same thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to log the files owned by user as there's no writing out to disk until the whole process is completed:

```
[string]$fileowned +=  $file.fullname|?{$f.owner -eq $username -or $f.owner -eq $AD_username}
```

Once out of loop, then write resulting $logfile out to disk:

```
$fileowned|out-file $logfile
```

By the way, you're using $d twice; once for get-date and next for the compare string.